# Binding Dictionary of Dictionaries Value C#

Tags: c#, data-binding

I have a dictionary, that is used to keep track of threads completing visually.

```
Dictionary<MyObject, Dictionary<string, bool>> taskDictionary
```

and I am trying to bind the values of the inner dictionary to a listView.End goal is something like this:

### MyObject     | task1  | Task2

object1Name    false    false

Currently I am able to get the name, but not the bools. Current approach is.

```
var gridView = new GridView();
foreach (var entry in taskDictionary) {
    Myobject obj = entry.key;
    gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn { Header = "Name", DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(Key.Name)});
    foreach (var secondDictionary in entry.Value) {
         // this line would bind to the taskDictionary[Key].Value
         gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn { Header = secondDictionary.Keym DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Value.Value")}); // what would be in this binding.
         listView.View = gridView;
    }
    break; // so we only add the task columns once.
}
listView.View = gridView;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is Binding("Value[" + secondDictionary.Key + "]")});

```
 gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn { Header = secondDictionary.Key DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Value.Value")});
```